# Is there anyway to make a vanilla mail system?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What I want to do is that when someone has ran a command, a tellraw text runs a command and when you press it, you can type a message to one particular person, who's offline on the server you're on.
When you have finished typing the message, the command block will activate and will tell you this message: "Mail send!".
When the receiver of your message comes online, they will get a tellraw message with a run_command saying: "You received 1 mail!", and when they click on the message it will show the message you typed for him/her.

But I don't know how to do this, I know how to do some stuff, but I don't know how to make it detect for a player when he/she says something in the chat.

Comment: This is incredibly ambitious, if not impossible in vanilla Minecraft.  You're better off just leaving signed books or signs for the other person.

Comment: This is definitely not possible in vanilla Minecraft, because there is no way for command blocks to extract information out of the chat. The only way this could be achieved is with written books, and maybe a setup that assigns a chest to each player.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible with vanilla command blocks to detect, nor somehow store and repeat to another player, what a player has said in chat.

As MBraedley has said, you would be better off making a system with signed books or signs.